# DataBricks (10.2) Undocumented Case Sensitivity Related to Feature Store Database/Table Access

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, feature-store

I created an input table intended to feed DataBricks Feature Store, mounting it (in Linux) and calling it as proscribed in DataBricks documentation (from their "RawDatasets" code example):

```
SourceDataFrameName_df = spark \
  .read \
  .format('delta') \
  .load("dbfs:/mnt/path/dev/version/database_name.tablename_extension")
```

However, this call fails with a "not-found"/"doesn't exist" error report related to locating the "database_name.tablename_extension" resource.  This is how the name displays everywhere within the DataBricks GUI - that is as all lower-case.

I spent much time reviewing DataBricks documentation and SO while reviewing my DataBricks system setup but cannot find the solution to this error.  Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an as-yet undocumented issue related to the nature of DataBricks Feature Store operations.  Since DataBricks is largely pass-through (using registered views rather than storing the source data), the mount is a key issue here.

This issue may not be documented/highlighted adequately in their documentation because it is actually a Linux-thing, since that operating system is case-sensitive (whereas DataBricks appears to be largely case-agnostic).  In this example, the original database/Linux engineer created the table/mount this way:

```
database_name.TableName_Extension
```

Since the mount references a Linux path, the path is case-sensitive, too.  So, the proper way to load this source dataset from such a mount would be:

```
SourceDataFrameName_df = spark \
  .read \
  .format('delta') \
  .load("dbfs:/mnt/path/dev/version/database_name.TableName_Extension")
```

The problem is that this case-sensitive nomenclature could potentially be unknown (and unknowable) if the DataBricks developer/engineer and the database/Linux developer/engineer are not the same person!  For example, it might have been labeled "database_name.Tablename_extension" or "database_name.TableName_EXTENSION" or any other combination thereof.

Obviously, this information isn't difficult to find, if the needy user knows to look for it.  Beware.

Comment: file names were always case-sensitive. It's only database/table names are case-insensitive by default

Comment: Exactly - the problem is that the DataBricks 10.2 GUI fails to reflect this sensitivity - OR - DataBricks falls to enforce the corresponding lack thereof.  Either way, this can be a hair-puller for those who are not familiar with Linux (since Windows is not case-sensitive).  Thanks for the reply!